# Using predictive modelling for temperature data set

Tags: data-mining, missing-data, data-imputation

I am absolutely new to this area of predictive modelling in data science. I am not able to understand how and what modelling techniques do we use? Does it depend on the data type? Does it depend on size of data?

To be specific to the title, I have to predict missing values in a given temperature data set and i am unaware of anything that i can use. Could someone guide me through?

Comment: What data do you have, beyond temperature values? What features are associated with each data point? Time, location?

Comment: year, month, min temp, max temp.
these are the only attributes that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to understand how and what modelling techniques do we
>   use?

Every data science workflow has the follwing steps:

1. Pre-processing (data cleaning and wrangling)
2. Exploratory analytics
3. Model selection
4. Prediction and testing.  (And re-iteration)
5. (Optional) Reporting the workflow

> Does it depend on the data type?

Yes, the entire workflow is dependent on the type and features of the data.

> Does it depend on size of data?

Size of data makes a difference in the tools and sometimes(very rarely) the algorithms used.

> I have to predict missing values in a given temperature data set and i
>   am unaware of anything that i can use

There is a [lot of](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-data?sort=newest&pageSize=50) [material](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-data) and algorithms on how to impute missing data, which you can refer to and use them accordingly depending on the type of data and the problem statement.

Comment: can you also help me with how i should go forward with learning and building a hold onto data science?

Comment: @SagarGhai I might not be able to, due to time constraints. However, there is plenty of material over Quora and this SE for getting up to speed. Good Luck :)